# AWS S3 Lambda Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-lambda

Trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.rackspace.com/the-devnull-s3-bucket-hacking-with-aws-lambda-and-python) and I keep getting "Access Denied" when running my Lambda. The Lambda is the default `s3-python-get-object`.

The role for the lambda is

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The user has admin privileges. I just don't get why it's going wrong.

Comment: Does the S3 bucket have a bucket policy attached? If so, add that to your question.

Comment: I don't think my bucket has a policy.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html):

```
If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.

If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.
```

The code above seems right for the operation you do.
Please make sure you have the key you are calling or add `s3:ListBucket` permission to be sure of the kind of error.